# not getting appilcation/json in content-type in header

Tags: php, json, jquery, cakephp

I want to send data and get response as JSON for fast response. So i am using AJAX. 
Why i am getting

"**Content-Type          text/html; charset=UTF-8**"

Why not getting

**Content-Type          application/json**

**Controller**

```
 public function testingMethod() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        $urlVal = $_POST['urlVal'];
        $dataBack = json_encode($urlVal);
        if ($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
            return $dataBack;
        }
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: pathname+"Frontends/testingMethod",
      data: 'urlVal=' + urlVal, 
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        alert(result);
     }
    });
```

**Header**

```
Response Headers

Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Length  2382
Content-Type    text/html; charset=UTF-8     //why here not getting application/json
Date    Wed, 14 Aug 2013 10:17:38 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=94
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.4.3
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.4.3
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with JQuery, but you almost certainly need to set a "Content-Type" header value (to "application/json") when you perform the POST. Otherwise it probably just defaults.

Comment: You’re not actually sending a `Content-Type` header, that’s why.

Answer (score 2):

Quick checklist:

1. Add the `.json` extension to `routes.php`:

   ```
   Router::parseExtensions('json');
   ```
2. Load the `RequestHandler` class in your controller:

   ```
   public $components = array(
       'RequestHandler',
   );
   ```
3. Create a `json` folder inside your model's `View` directory and place JSON view there.
4. Append `.json` to the URL:

   ```
   url: pathname+"Frontends/testingMethod.json",
   ```

This is documented at [JSON and XML views](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html). It's worth reading the full document because the steps I've described are not the only possible way to do it.